# Pasar un parametro al Report Viewer

Tags: c#

Hola amigos tengo un parametro de un metodo C# que quiero que se muestre en un reporte rdlc

```js
public static void getPerfil(){

   String perfil = "ESTE ES MI PERFIL";
}
```

Lo quiero agregar donde esta en la carpeta Parametro para ponerlo en mi reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agregar parámetros a la carpeta es sencillo, solo necesitas dar click derecho y luego dar click en agregar, creo que tu pregunta va mas enfocada a como enviar los parámetros al reporte. Para ello primero necesitas instanciar un array de la clase ReportParameter como te muestro a continuación:

```
        ReportParameter[] reportParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
        reportParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("NombreParametro", "VALOR DE TU PARAMETRO", false);
```

Después si tienes tu reporte en un ReportViewer deberás acceder a la propiedad LocalReport y posteriormente agregar los parámetros:

```
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

En caso que no tengas un ReportViewer, accede directamente a la propiedad de tu reporte:

```
        TuReporte..SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Mi reporte esta en una  carpeta , bueno mi reporte en esta caso se llamado ReportePerfil.rdlc y el reportViewer1 como lo obtengo

Comment: Estás trabajando en Winforms, MVC o Webforms?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con MVC

Answer (score 0):

Aca cuando es cuando genero el reporte va a este controller para generar el reporte pdf

```js
        public static async Task<Byte[]> GetFileComunicado(String Supervisor, String Paciente, long CodigoAtencionMedica, String Location, long CodigoUsuarioSistema)
        {
            ReportDataSource Encabezado = new ReportDataSource
            {
                Name = "Encabezado",
                Value = ExamenDAL.SupervisorToDatatable(Supervisor, "Nombre")
            };

            ReportDataSource Restriccion = new ReportDataSource
            {
                Name = "Restriccion",
                Value = await GetRestriccionByAtencion(Paciente, CodigoAtencionMedica)
            };

            ReportDataSource From = new ReportDataSource
            {
                Name = "From",
                Value = await ExamenDAL.GetMedicoByUsuarioSistema(CodigoUsuarioSistema)
            };

            ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer
            {
                ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
            };
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Encabezado);
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Restriccion);
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(From);
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = "COM-RESTRICCION-MEDICO";
            reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Location) + @"Reports\ReportePerfil.rdlc";
            return reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");
```

Comment: A tu código solo le hace falta que le envíes los parámetros al reportViewer. La única diferencia es que yo llamé a mi instancia reportViewer1, y tu llamaste simplemente reportViewer.